# MirrorMakerv2.0 Strimzi

Tags: apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have created a TLS configuration for mirrormaker2 (mm2) and am getting the following error:

> ERROR Scheduler for MirrorSourceConnector caught exception in scheduled task: refreshing topics (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.Scheduler) [Scheduler for MirrorSourceConnector-refreshing topics] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1633531333434, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1633531333535) timed out at 1633531333435 after 1 attempt(s) 
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45) 
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32) 
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89) 
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260) 
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector.listTopics(MirrorSourceConnector.java:392) 
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector.findSourceTopicPartitions(MirrorSourceConnector.java:194) 
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector.refreshTopicPartitions(MirrorSourceConnector.java:218) 
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:93) 
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.Scheduler.executeThread(Scheduler.java:112) 
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.Scheduler.lambda$scheduleRepeatingDelayed$1(Scheduler.java:57) 
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) 
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) 
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) 
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) \

What is missing?